# Why doesn't umask work as expected?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, umask

Please, can someone explain this to me?
I set:

```
umask 000
touch afile.tmp
```

result:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 jay apache 0 Aug 16 18:11 afile.tmp
```

I was expecting this:

```
-rw-rw-rw-
```

to be like this:

```
-rwxrwxrwx
```

Why isn't umask setting the '`x`'`s  of the permissions for new file modifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`umask` is working precisely as expected - a mask of 0000 means permissions are 666 (`rw-rw-rw-`) for files and 777 (`rwxrwxrwx`) for directories. The execute bit is set for directories and not files. Case in point: the default umask is 0022, but files you create don't have the execute bit set by default, do they?

Comment: 022 yields only -rw-r--r--.So, umask can't change the execute bits?

Comment: @Ted not for files.